# Как повысить скорость анимации живых обоев?

Tags: javascript, node.js, файловая-система, livewallpaper

Я сделал для себя живые обои используя Node.js. В принципе, все работает, вот код:

```
const fileSystem = require("fs");

const wallpaper = require("wallpaper");

const { Canvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const canvas = new Canvas(1920, 1080);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let pos = 0;
setInterval (() => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(pos, 200, 150, 150);

    pos = (pos + 1) % 1920;

    const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png')
    fileSystem.writeFileSync('./image.png', buffer);

    (async () => {
        await wallpaper.set("./image.png");
    })();
}, 1000 / 60);
```

Но есть проблема - анимация идет со скоростью примерно в 10 fps. Кроме того, постоянное сохранение картинки и установка ее в качестве обоев загружают мне процессор на 70-80%, что не есть хорошо.

Как лучше реализовать эту идею?

Кстати, сейчас заметил, что в моем алгоритме есть еще одна проблема - если Node.js очень часто обращается к одному файлу, доступ к нему блокируется и выдается EBUSY Error. Так что, с этим тоже нужно что-то придумать.

Comment: Давно такого извращения не видел 

Comment: в этом весь я)))

Comment: эту идею лучше реализовать анимированным gif

Comment: Можно, но тогда сгенерировать в real time это не получится(((

Answer (score 6):

> Как лучше реализовать эту идею?

Занятный вопрос. Конечно, вашу идею лучше реализовывать через любой инструмент анимации. Я в них не разбираюсь, так что в качестве примера приведу анимированный gif. Это - единственный способ минимизировать задержки анимации. Сгенерировать 100 фреймов, записать в файл и заняться генерацией следующего набора фреймов.

Но в комментариях вы настаивали на том, что вам нужна real-time генерация, так что давайте подумаем о том что можно улучшить.

Основная претензия к библиотеке canvas - она непозволительно медленная для вашей задачи. Генерация каждого фрейма на моём ноуте длится 150-170ms.

```
wallpaper-canvas: 170.962ms
wallpaper-canvas: 156.34ms
wallpaper-canvas: 157.196ms
wallpaper-canvas: 159.465ms
wallpaper-canvas: 154.248ms
wallpaper-canvas: 158.292ms
wallpaper-canvas: 164.503ms
wallpaper-canvas: 153.939ms
wallpaper-canvas: 164.663ms
wallpaper-canvas: 154.713ms
wallpaper-canvas: 163.566ms
wallpaper-canvas: 159.067ms
```

#### Нужен *нормальный* инструмент

Берём [**sharp**](https://github.com/lovell/sharp).

Пишем примерно такую штуку:

- делаем холст размером с ваш квадратик и заливаем чёрным
- расширяем холст до размеров экрана и заливаем "расширитель" белым
- при выгрузке в png убираем компрессию до минимума, но так, чтобы экономия на компрессии не начала влиять на время записи на диск
- и ещё одна важная штука: если писать в файл так, как это делаете вы то будут несколько мгновений когда файл картинки будет неполным, не валидным. делаем запись атомарной, при генерации пишем во временный файл, а потом переименовываем временный файл в "основное" название.

#### Исходник

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const truefile = path.join(__dirname, 'image.png');
const tmpfile = path.join(__dirname, 'image.png.tmp');
const screen = {
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080,
};
const rect = {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  x: 0,
  y: 200
};

let fn;
(fn = async () => {
  rect.bb = {
    top: rect.y,
    bottom: screen.height - rect.height - rect.y,
    left: rect.x,
    right: screen.width - rect.width - rect.x
  };

  const buf = await makeFrame();
  fs.writeFileSync(tmpfile, buf);
  fs.renameSync(tmpfile, truefile);

  rect.x = (rect.x + 1) % (screen.width - rect.width);

  setTimeout(fn, 10);
})();

/**
 * @returns {Promise<Buffer>}
 */
async function makeFrame() {
  const image = sharp({
    create: {
      width: rect.width,
      height: rect.height,
      channels: 3,
      background: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}
    }
  });

  image.extend({
    ...rect.bb,
    background: {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255}
  });

  image.png({
    compressionLevel: 1
  });

  return image.toBuffer();
}
```

#### Результат работы

Среднее время генерации фрейма на моём ноуте равно 22ms. Ускорился почти на порядок!

А дальше можно хитрить: можно узнать у операционки разрешение экрана и генерировать картинку, например, в 1.5-2 раза меньшего размера. Пускать операционка натягивает её на экран, она это умеет.
Пропорционально уменьшив в 2 раза все атрибуты `rect` и `rect.bb` я получил время генерации фрейма равное 9-10ms, а это уже - очень хорошее время, прям real time.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sub>Замечу, что вызов `await wallpaper.set("./image.png")` выполняется оочень долго. По сути, теперь именно он стал узким местом. Но, я уверен, можно найти быстрые низкоуровневые способы рассказать OS о том, что у неё новые обои. Я же исследовал только генерацию картинок.</sub>

Comment: нужно ещё попробовать добавить в скрипт oxipng для оптимизации картинки на выходе ([тыц](https://github.com/shssoichiro/oxipng), [тыц](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/wasm-codecs/tree/master/packages/oxipng)). он зачищает .png c 31282 байт до размера 1174 байт, но вряд ли он обеспечит общий прирост по скорости

Comment: Слушай, и правда гораздо быстрее. Попробую, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

для начала попробуй использовать рекурсивный таймер. 
https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#rekursivnyy-settimeout 
когда ты 60 раз в секунду переписываешь файл, он не успевает закрыться и может выдать ошибку EBUSY 
А вообще как писали выше в комментариях к вопросу, лучше сделать это через gif анимацию